# Determine the type of a (not built in) class in python

Tags: python, class, instances

I've got a grid representing a tessellation, which is a set of instances of the `Polygon` class (a class I made). I also have a `Boundary` class, which is the class representing the boundary of the simulation I'm running (another class I've made). Any line of any pentagon can either have two `Polygon` objects or a `Polygon` and a `Boundary` object as "parents" (an attribute which I've defined for the line class). The type of the object determines how I do certain computations.

So, in short, I need a way to tell which of two classes a particular variable is an instance of, where I've made both classes. When I call `type(parent)`, I get:

```
 <type 'instance'>
```

How am I supposed to determine this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/54873

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way to perform typechecking in Python is to use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(x, Boundary):
    # x is of type Boundary
elif isinstance(x, Polygon):
    # x is of type Polygon
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Boundary:
...     pass
...
>>> x = Boundary()
>>> isinstance(x, Boundary)
True
>>>
```

Note that doing `type(x) is Boundary` would also work, but it will not factor in inheritance like `isinstance` does.

Answer (score 0):

In old-style classes you check the class of an instance using its `__class__` attribute, in new-style classes `type()` will work fine(Read: [NewClass Vs Classic Class](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass)). In old-style classes every instance of user-defined class was of type `instance`([Unifying types and classes in Python 2.2](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/)).

```
>>> a = A()
>>> class A:
    pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__class__
<class __main__.A at 0x7fcce57b1598>
>>> a.__class__ is A
True
```

In new-style classes `type(ins`) and `ins.__class__` now do the same thing:

```
>>> class B(object): # Inherit from object to create new-style class
    pass
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> type(b)
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> b.__class__
<class '__main__.B'>
```

You can also use `isinstance()` to check if an object is an instance of a class:

```
>>> isinstance(a, A)
True
>>> isinstance(b, B)
True
```

But checking this using `isinstance` doesn't mean the class is the exact parent of the instance:

```
>>> class C(B):
    pass
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> isinstance(c, B)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the `__class__` attribute of your object:

```
class Class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # Object created

obj = Class()
print obj.__class__ == Class
```